# Mathematical formula conversion

Tags: math, wolfram-mathematica

Ok. I have formula for find "d" but i need new formula to find "A".

```
d=sqrt(((1.27*A)/coef))
```

For example i have:
d=0.36
coef=10

I need A and A in new formula must be 1.
Think it's school level question.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/?as=1

Answer (score 0):

```
d=sqrt(((1.27*A)/coef))
d^2 = (1.27*A)/coef
coef*d^2 = (1.27*A)
coef*d^2/1.27 = A

A = coef*d^2/1.27
```

Answer (score 0):

here you go:

```
A= (coef * d * d)/ 1.27
```

Answer (score 0):

Your equation says to take A and...

- Multiply by 1.27
- Divide by coef
- Take the square root

... to get `d`. So, to get `A` starting from `d` you need to work backwards, undoing each step:

- Square
- Multiply by coef
- Divide by 1.27

Or, in equation form, `A = d^2 * coef / 1.27`.

The math used to read and manipulate equations like this is called "Algebra".